# Wrong Typeclass Instance used in Coq Proof

Tags: functional-programming, coq, typeclass, dependent-type, theorem-proving

I'm trying to perform the following proof based on Finite Maps as defined in CoqExtLib. However, I'm having a problem where the instance of `RelDec` showing up in the proof is different than the instance that I think is declared.

```
Require Import ExtLib.Data.Map.FMapAList.
Require ExtLib.Structures.Sets.
Module DSet := ExtLib.Structures.Sets.          
Require ExtLib.Structures.Maps.
Module Map := ExtLib.Structures.Maps.
Require Import ExtLib.Data.Nat.
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.

Definition Map k v := alist k v.
Definition loc := nat.
Definition sigma : Type := (Map loc nat).


Lemma not_in_sigma : forall (l l' : loc) (e : nat) (s : sigma),
    l <> l' ->
    Map.lookup l ((l',e)::s) = Map.lookup l s.
  intros. simpl. assert ( RelDec.rel_dec l l' = true -> l = l').
  pose (ExtLib.Core.RelDec.rel_dec_correct l l') as i. destruct i.

(*i := RelDec.rel_dec_correct l l' : RelDec.rel_dec l l' = true <-> l >= l'*)
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use the fact that `rel_dec` must evaluate to false if its two inputs are not equal. This seems to match the definition given in ExtLib.Data.Nat:

`Global Instance RelDec_eq : RelDec (@eq nat) :=
{ rel_dec := EqNat.beq_nat }.`

However, in the code I showed above, it's using `>=` instead of `=` as the relation that the finite map is parameterized on, so I can't apply the theorem `rel_dec_correct`.

Why is this happening? How is the instance for RelDec being chosen? Is there something special I need to do when proving theorems about types qualified by typeclasses? How can I get a version of `rel_dec_correct` that applies to equality, not greater-than?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this issue you might want to set `Debug Typeclasses` option:

```
Set Debug Typeclasses.
assert ( RelDec.rel_dec l l' = true -> l = l').
```

or, alternatively, use `Set Printing Implicit` to reveal the instances Coq has picked up.

The latter shows us that it is `RelDec_ge` as the goal now has the following form:

```
@RelDec.rel_dec loc ge RelDec_ge l l' = true -> l = l'
```

Apparently Coq chose the instance which is wrong for your purposes, however you can lock the relation you want like so:

```
assert ( RelDec.eq_dec l l' = true -> l = l').
```

Now `apply (RelDec.rel_dec_correct l l').` resolves the goal, but `pose` won't work, since there is no information that would tie the goal to a useful instance. The `pose` tactic would just find an instance of `RelDec nat <rel>` (you can list all of them with this vernacular: `Print Instances RelDec.RelDec.`).

There is a very nice [tutorial on typeclasses](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/draft/qc-current/Typeclasses.html) by B.C. Pierce you might want to have a look at.